# Android SQLite ORDER BY not working in query

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-order-by

I have a DB with 6 fields, and I want to do a query ordering it by "num"

```
c=myDbHelper.query(m_db, new String[] {"_cod", "nombre", "flag", "cod_url", "tipo_l_menu", "num"}, null, null, null, null, "num");
```

With this I get the query but it is not sorted. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is num integer or string? try adding ASC or DESC to num - 'num DESC'

Comment: num is type INT in SQLite db. I tried adding ASC but same result :(

Comment: can you put some sample data and what is happening with the data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Cursor c = mydbhelper.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM myTable Order By num",null);
```

Comment: @Yaqub Ahmad: do you have an idea _why_ the above doesn't work? Have a similar issue right now ...

Answer (score 3):

Please Check the below code its working for me.

```
"SELECT  * FROM " +<Table-Name>+" ORDER BY cast(<enter Name of Column> as REAL) DESC/ASC;";
```

And you can get data in sorted order